# Grouping by function value into Multimap

Tags: haskell, grouping, multimap

Assuming I have a list of values like this:

```haskell
["abc","abd","aab","123"]
```

I want to group those values into a MultiMap (conceptually, not limited to a specific data structure) in Haskell by using a function that maps any element to a key.

For this example, we shall use `take 2` as a mapper.

The result I intend to get is (conceptually, as JSON):

```
{"ab":["abc","abd"], "aa":["aab"], "12":["123"]}
```

In this example I will use `[(String, [String])]` as a Multimap data structure.

My basic idea (conceptually):

```haskell
let datalist = ["abc","abd","aab","123"]
let mapfn = take 2
let keys = nub $ map mapfn datalist
let valuesForKey key = filter ((==key).mapfn) datalist
let resultMultimap = zip keys $ map valuesForKey keys
```

My question:

1. Is there any better way (in base or external packages) to do this? I want to avoid custom code.
2. If 1) is not applicable, is there any guarantee that GHC will optimize this so one pass over the data list is sufficient to generate the full multimap (as opposed to one `filter` run per key)?

Conceptually, this question is similar to the SQL `GROUP BY` statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [`fromListWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v%3afromListWith) from [`Data.Map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Map.html):

```
> let xs = ["abc","abd","aab","123"]
> let f = take 2
> Data.Map.fromListWith (++) [(f x, [x]) | x <- xs]
fromList [("12",["123"]),("aa",["aab"]),("ab",["abd","abc"])]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me resolving this issue! I put this newly-gained knowledge into code by creating reusable functions for the problem I asked for and for a more-generalized form (see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22123586/2597135) ).

Answer (score 2):

**Edit 2014-03-28:** My functions have now been published on Hackage, see [group-with](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/group-with)

[Pull requests](https://github.com/ulikoehler/group-with) are welcome!

---

Based on [hammar's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22027081/2597135) I put together two reusable functions to solve this problem.

`groupWith` solves exactly what I asked for. `groupWithMulti` generalizes the concept by allowing the identifier-generating function (e.g. `take 2` in my example) to return multiple identifiers for a single value (where the value is, in my example, one of `["abc","abd","aab","123"]`), or none at all.
The value will be added to the `Map` value for any identifier generated by `f`.

```haskell
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map

-- | Group values in a list by their identifier, being returned
--   by a given function. The resulting map contains,
--   for each generated identifier the values (from the original list)
--   that yielded said identifier by using the function
groupWith :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> [a] -> (Map b [a])
groupWith f xs = Map.fromListWith (++) [(f x, [x]) | x <- xs]

-- | Like groupWith, but the identifier-generating function
--   may generate multiple outputs (or even none).
--   The corresponding value from the original list will be placed
--   in the identifier-corresponding map entry for each generated
--   identifier
groupWithMulti :: (Ord b) => (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> (Map b [a])
groupWithMulti f xs = 
  let identifiers x = [(val, [x]) | val <- f x]
  in Map.fromListWith (++) $ concat [identifiers x | x <- xs]
```

Simply use `Map.toList` to convert the results of these functions back to a tuple list.

When I have some spare time, I will attempt to create a generalized library on Hackage out of this approach on in-memory data grouping.